# Django admin Исключить значение из InlineformSet

Tags: django, inline, queryset

Есть две модели:

```
class User(models.Model):
    main = models.OneToOneField('Char', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='main')

class Char(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

P.s: Суть заключается в том у пользователя может быть несколько персонажей, но основной только один из них ( надеюсь я правильно реализовал это на моделях )

К сути проблемы, добавляю InlineFormset_factory к Пользователю в админку, соответственно на странице редактирования пользователя у него отображаются персонажи, в том числе и тот, который находится в поле main, вопрос как можно его исключить?

```
CharFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, Char, exclude=())

class CharInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Char
    formset = CharFormSet
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False
```

Пробовал у класса CharInline в методе get_queryset изменить сам queryset, но не знаю как получить именно нужного пользователя, а не request.user

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему путем добавления метода get_inline_formsets в регистрацию модели. Хоть и не нравится, что необходимо указывать индекс нужного формсета.

```
@admin.register(User, site=admin_site)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_inline_formsets(self, request, formsets, inline_instances, obj=None):
        formsets[-1].queryset = Char.objects.filter(user=obj).exclude(id=obj.main_id)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_inline_formsets(request, formsets, inline_instances)
```